# Create unit test with Jest and React testing library for helper which generate a domain url

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, window, react-router-dom, react-testing-library

I created a helper function to generate a url with the domain in the url:

```
const generateUrl = () => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    return window.location.href;
  }
  return null;
};

export default generateUrl;
```

I need to write a unit test for this function. I am using Jest and React testing library.

```
import { Location } from 'react-router-dom';

import generateUrl from './generate-url';

// function mock(pathname: string): Location {
//  return {
//    pathname,
//  };
// }

describe('generateUrl', () => {
  it('should display url with domain', () => {
    expect(
      generateUrl().toStrictEqual('http://localhost:3000/?id=e3f3ef3f');
  });

});
```

How do I write a test for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You could mock the `window.location` object for the unit test.

```
import generateUrl from './generate-url';

describe('generateUrl', () => {
  it('should display url with domain', () => {
    // save a reference of the window object
    const windowCache = window;

    // update the location.href property
    window.location = {
      href: 'http://localhost:3000/?id=e3f3ef3f',
    };

    // test
    expect(generateUrl()).toStrictEqual('http://localhost:3000/?id=e3f3ef3f');

    // restore cached window reference
    window = windowCache;
  });
});
```